# ElasticBeanstalk change a file

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to add analytics code to an HTML file in a ElasticBeanstalk app. I just want to change one HTML file.

I don't want to update my app completely. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the instruction in below documentation where it is mentioned step by step on how you can update your application. They have shown this update by just updating one file which is index.php.

[Update an Application with AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/update-an-app/)

To summarise, below are high-level steps :

1. if you have .zip file of your existing code then unzip it.
2. Make the changes in that one file.
3. Zip it again.
4. Upload it in the Application Version with a different name and click on deploy.
5. Your updated code will be deployed.

To update the file without the downtime, please use EB provided Deployment Strategies which avoid any downtime.

[Deploying Applications to AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environments](http://You%20can%20refer%20to%20this%20one%20as%20well%20as%20it%20has%20other%20strategies%20as%20well.%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.deploy-existing-version.html)

Below are the three strategies which you can utilize :

1. Rolling with additional batch
2. Immutable
3. [Blue/green](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html)

Comment: Thanks @Pacifist . But I read this article. This instruction stops the app, updates it, then starts it. I don't want any downtime for a little change. If I can't find a way, I will do this that way.

Comment: @emert117 In case you don't want the downtime then you can use EB provided deployment strategy. In Rolling with additional batch, Immutable, Blue/green deployment strategy there's no downtime.

Comment: Thanks @Pacifist. I will try to learn what you mentioned. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html

Comment: @emert117 You're Welcome. You can refer to this one as well as it has other strategies also. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.deploy-existing-version.html